# Laravel X-editable

Tags: php, laravel, x-editable

I try to use X-editable in laravel 5.5 but can't get it to work. So far I have this controller:

```
public function updatecommentajax(Request $request)
    {
      return Rating::find($id)->update([
        'comment' => $request->get('comment'),
      ]);
    }
```

This is my Route:

```
Route::post('/updatecommentajax/{id}', 'RatingController@updatecommentajax')->name('updatecommentajax');
```

Here is my Blade:

```
<form action="{{route('updatecommentajax', $rating->id)}}" method="post">
  {{csrf_field()}}
  <td class="text-center">
    <a href="#" id="comment" class="comment" data-url="{{ route('updatecommentajax', $rating->id) }}" data-pk="{{ $rating->id }}" data-type="textarea" data-placement="right" data-title="Edit Comment">{{$rating->comment}}</a>
  </td>
</form>
```

And my JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  //toggle `popup` / `inline` mode
  $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'popup';

    rating_id = $(this).data('pk');
    url = $(this).data('url');

    //make username editable
    $('#comment').editable({
      url: url,
      pk: rating_id,
      headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
      type:"POST",
      validate:function(value){
        if($.trim(value) === '')
        {
          return 'This field is required';
        }
      }
    });
});
</script>
```

Anyone know what's the issue?

> PS: Somehow only first comment will be selected for edit and others no (guess is because `id="comment"` but if i change it to `{{$rating->id}}` I don't know later how to get it in this part `$('#comment').editable({`

[image: edit]

## UPDATE

I managed to make it work but the issue in my `PS` above still exist. here is my fix codes:

Blade:

```
<form action="{{route('updatecommentajax', $rating->id)}}" method="post">
  {{csrf_field()}}
  <td class="text-center">
   <label for="comment" hidden></label>
   <a href="#" id="comment" class="comment" data-url="{{ route('updatecommentajax', $rating->id) }}" data-pk="{{ $rating->id }}" data-type="textarea" data-placement="right" data-title="Edit Comment">{{$rating->comment}}</a>
 </td>
</form>
```

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  //toggle `popup` / `inline` mode
  $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';
  $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    rating_id = $(this).data('pk');
    url = $(this).data('url');

    //make username editable
    $('#comment').editable({
      url: url,
      pk: rating_id,
      type:"textarea",
      validate:function(value){
        if($.trim(value) === '')
        {
          return 'This field is required';
        }
      }
    });


    $('#rating').editable({
      url: url,
      pk: rating_id,
      type:"select",
      source: [
      {value: 1, text: '1 Star'},
      {value: 2, text: '2 Star'},
      {value: 3, text: '3 Star'},
      {value: 4, text: '4 Star'},
      {value: 5, text: '5 Star'}
      ],
      validate:function(value){
        if($.trim(value) === '')
        {
          return 'This field is required';
        }
      }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## SOLVED

1. My fix code is in my question update part
2. My PS that was still exist I fixed it by changing `$('#comment').editable({` to `$('.comment').editable({`  Id to Class.

Hope it help others.